# Python turing machine for 0^n1^n2^n

Tags: python, turing-machines

I was given the instructions "Create a Turing machine to recognize string of the form 0^n1^n2^n. This means that if the string is of the correct form, the Turing machine stops on a blank tape, while if it is not of the correct form it stops on a non-blank cell".

I know the basics of how a Turing machine works, but no idea how to implement one in Python. Any examples I've found online seem very complex, with multiple classes and everything. I don't think that is completely necessary or expected for my application.

I found the following psuedocode for this problem:

```
On input string w
   while there are unmarked 0s, do
      Mark the left most 0
      Scan right to reach the leftmost unmarked 1;
         if there is no such 1 then crash
      Mark the leftmost 1
      Scan right to reach the leftmost unmarked 2;
         if there is no such 2 then crash
      Mark the leftmost 2
   done
   Check to see that there are no unmarked 1s or 2s;
      if there are then crash
   accept
```

However, it seems to me that implementing this exact pseudocode would not really end up being a legitimate turing machine. Am I going about this the wrong way? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That pesudo code seems correct to me, it might help if you showed us an example of what would be acceptable for a less complex problem, I don't know exactly what is accepted in the TM in python.

Comment: In order to implement that code, how would you go about "marking" an item in the given string? And I don't see how the "head" or "tape" of a turing machine would fit in then.

Comment: Just consider 3 to be the 'mark' character. Whenever you wanna mark a space just set it to 3. You don't even really need to know what was under the mark so it should work just fine.